# how can I match user input with index of the dictionary?

Tags: python, input, indexing

I want to identify which currency user want to withdraw from:

```
account = {"USD": 10, "HKD": 10000}
for index,key in account.keys():
  print(index,".",key)
```

output:

1.USD

2.HKD

```
currency_selected = int(input("Please select currency: ")
if currency_selected == index:
  input("How much do you want to withdraw?")
else:
  print("Error! Please try again")
```

When I input 1/2 for choosing the currency, it always go to the error message.
How can I match the int user input to the currency number?

Comment: 1/2 is a currency?

Comment: I mean when I input 1 or 2 to choose the currency

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you using dictionary! If you want to use dictionary and detect user desired currency, you're gonna need a function that is called **Surjective Function** in mathematics (You can read about different types of math functions [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html)). In this function, you should correspond different states of input to one of your currencies. Something like this would be nice I think:

```
currencies = {"1.USD" : "your value", "2.HKD" : "your value"}
usercurrency = input("Enter the currency that you want to use: ")
usercurrencyedited = usercurrency.lower()
for curr in currencies:
    if usercurrencyedited in currencies[curr]:
    print("You preference is " + curr)
```

In this code, we check both the number, and the string, Note that I used `usercurrencyedited = usercurrency.lower()` because user may not enter the currency capitalized.

Good luck :D

new edit:
If you just want to check index in the dictionary and do not user any numbers in dictionary key, you can use this code:

```
currencies = {"USD" : "your value", "HKD" : "your value"}
userinput = input("Enter your preferred currency.")
currentindex = 1
for curr in currencies:
    if currentindex == int(userinput):
        print("Your preference is " + curr)
        break
    currentindex += 1
```

Comment: Hey, as this is a college assignment, I have to fill the requirement that users want to input the number correspond to the currency. Is there any way that instead of asking the user to put  "USD", ask them to put 1. , and i can match the 1 get know they want USD?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? In this code, it also checks the number and there is no problem getting the number of the currency. If your problem is with the numbers in dictionary keys, I mean for example the '1' in {"1. USD" : "your value"}  you  can have and int i = 1 out of that for loop, then in every state add 1 to that and in every for loop state, check if the i is equal to the input.

Comment: In my full program ( which is an ATM program), the currency user has is shown by printing the index and key of the dictionary. So for the next part, I want them to in put the number shown correspond to each currency, and match their input with the index of dictionary

Comment: It only works when it is 1 for USD, but not other index for other currencies.